# Edit Nth occurence interactively in a search in vim

Tags: text-processing, vim

Given a text with multiple occurrences of the word `foo`, I would like to do an interactive search through the text, and upon the Nth occurrence of `foo`, edit it.

I can only find the `search and replace` patterns for this kind of action, but the point is that I do not want to edit all occurrences of `foo`, just the one I found in some context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read you correctly:

1. Search

   `/foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Next by <kbd>n</kbd>
3. *“Oh, this one I want to delete”*

   - <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
4. Continue by <kbd>n</kbd>
5. *“Oh, this one I want to change to `bar`”*

   - <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>`bar`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
6. Continue by <kbd>n</kbd> ...
7. *“Oh, this one I want to change to `baz`”*

   - <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>`baz`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
8. Continue by <kbd>n</kbd> ...

---

#### Edit / Correction:

For convenience I have added:

```
imap <C-d> <ESC>
```

to `.vimrc` - had forgotten about that and thought it was a default mapping. Corrected.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I would like to add that you need to do `enter` when you would like to make the "normal" operations (`cw` or the like) to the found occurrence.

Comment: @Steen: Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `c` flag when doing [search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace):

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

Each time `vim` found `foo`, it will prompt `yes/no` to confirm replacing or not.

Or if you want to search for the nth occurrence of `foo`, you can:

```
n/foo
```

Then `vim` will jump to nth occurrence of `foo`, so you can decide to replace or not.

Comment: Thanks, but as per my comment to @Thushi, I am looking for an interactive way of doing this.

Comment: @Steen: What do you mean interactive way? The above method do it interactively.

Comment: I mean interactive as when just casually browsing the file via `/{search-phrase}`, pressing `n` (or `p`) repeatedly and then stumbling over some occurrence of 'foo' that should not be there or be something else. When browsing a file, I just `/foo` and `n` for some file without knowing in advance whether or not I am going to be replacing stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but with your solution I get either/or. It is exactly _when_ "so you can decide to replace or not" happens, that I would like to press e.g. `ciw` to replace that occurrence of the word. I don't want to first search for a word, `n`-ing through the file, finding an occurrence I don't like, `esc`-ing and then doing `::%s/foo/bar/gc` to step through the file once more.

Answer (score 1):

For the normal search and replace option in `vim` you can use the confirmation option by passing `gc` for example.

For example if you want to replace the word `foo` with `bar` then you add the below line

`:%s/foo/bar/gc`

So wherever it finds the occurrence of the word `foo` it asks for the confirmation for replacement of word `bar`.If you press `y` it will be get replaced and `n` for no.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution when just casually browsing the file via `/{search-phrase}`, pressing `n` repeatedly  and then stumbling over some occurrence of 'foo' that should not be there or be something else. I have already found the answers when I up-front know that I'm going to (possibly or most likely) be replacing some text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global search 'g' to qualify which lines you should substitute on

```
:g/qualifyingregexp/s/foo/bar/igc
```

to further restrict you can even specify markers

```
:'a,'bg/qualifyingregexp/s/foo/bar/igc
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but please see the accepted answer for the correct interpretation of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat a lot of commands in `vim` by typing first the number how often they should be repeated. This also works for the `n` command.

To change e.g. the 9th occurrence of `foo` type

1. type `/foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>   to jump to the first location of `foo`
2. type `8n` to jump eight times to the the next location. Then you are are on the ninth occurrence
3. type `cw` to change the word and type in the new word.

You can continue the steps 2. and 3. as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180240/15241)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this case I don't know in advance how many (if any) `n`s there are.